# Show different data each request

Tags: php

I got some database data inside an array. Now I want to display 3 elements each page request.

Example:

```
Data: array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
First request:  1, 2, 3
Second request: 4, 5, 6
...
```

Comment: Then you don't want to shuffle it, but just slice the first 3 elements from your array and add it to the end.

Comment: @Rizier123 , Thanks for the reply

I will explain what actually i need. I am forming the array from mysql results and in first page I am displaying first 3 results . if the user refreshed the page i want the next 3 results in the first page

Comment: Well then you probably want to rewrite your question. You then need to keep track on the results with a session array or something like this over multiple requests.

Comment: As I said then you probably want to use the `$_SESSION` array to keep track of the results and displayed data over multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution and here is my code . Thanks everyone for the help

```
 <?php
               session_start();
               $array1=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
            $i=0;
    if(isset($_SESSION["firstthreeids"])){
    $value=$_SESSION["firstthreeids"];
        $prevarray=explode(",",$value);
        $displayids=array_diff($array1,$prevarray);
    }
    else{
        $displayids=$array1;
    }
foreach($displayids as $result){
    if($i==3){break;}
    $check[]=$result;   
    $i++;
}
if(count($displayids)==3){
    unset($_SESSION['firstthreeids']);
    session_destroy();
}
else{
    if(isset($_SESSION["firstthreeids"])){
        $_SESSION["firstthreeids"]=implode(",",$check).",".$_SESSION["firstthreeids"];
}
       else{    
          $_SESSION["firstthreeids"]=implode(",",$check);   
            }
          }

         print_r($displayids);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two php functions array_slice and array_merge.

**Step#1** Slice the first three elements of the array.

**Step#2** Merge These three elements with the remaining array elements.

```
<?php
function shuffle(arr){
  $first_three = array_slice(arr,0,3);
  $remaining_array = array_slice(arr,3);

  $new_array = array_merge($remaining_array,$first_three);

  return $new_array;
}

$numbers_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

shuffle($numbers_array);

?>
```

Comment: 1) `shuffle()` is already a built-in function which you can't overwrite 2) See OP's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011677/shuffle-an-array-in-a-specific-format#comment63466636_38011677

Comment: @Abdullah A Malik : Hi , Thanks for the help. but it always returns 4,5,6 :(

Comment: @Rizier123 : You are right . I have given a new name to that function and tried but it always returns 4,5,6 in the first page